# Running Flink on Windows causes error due to syntax formation

Tags: java, windows, apache-flink

I am trying to run Flink on Windows and I get the following error. All the examples I have seen so far are for Linux. Is it possible to run it on Windows?

Command:

```
flink.bat run --class WordCount D:\TestFlinkProject\dataflair\WordCount.jar --input file:D:\TestFlinkProject\dataflair\input.txt --output  file:D:\TestFlinkProject\dataflair\output.txt
```

Error:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
> java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI:
> file:D:/EclipseWorkspace/TestFlinkProject/dataflair/input.txt

Comment: You have to either remove the file: scheme, or replace it with file:///.

Comment: Also, file:D: is an invalid URI, as there must be at least one slash between the scheme and path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to specify the URI for the input file on Windows you have to use one of the following formats:

```
file:/D:/TestFlinkProject/dataflair/input.txt
file:///D:/TestFlinkProject/dataflair/input.txt
```